# PayPal JSON Response Object Transaction ID

Tags: php, paypal

I'm developing a Javascript / PHP / REST API and want to double check on the Transaction ID length. In most of the documentation it is stated that the JSON Response Object Transaction ID for a completed transaction is a unique 17 character string, however, the orderID is 19 characters long. The documentation states, "A valid transaction ID is 17 characters long, except for an order ID, which is 19 characters long." When I run tests, the order ID that is produced by PayPal and included in my URL (for the PHP processing page) is the same 17 character string as the transaction ID.

As this must be inserted into the database a sudden change in character length can cause problems. Are the transaction ID and the order ID always one and the same? Will they differ in certain situations? Getting clarity on this will be helpful. Thanks a bunch for the assistance!
Cheers,
shackleton

Answer (score 1):

Using the v2 REST APIs, order IDs are 17 characters long, same format as transaction IDs.

If you find a reference to 19 character order IDs (ones that begin with an `O-` prefix), you are reading legacy v1 REST or Classic NVP/SOAP API documentation.

Comment: Thank you Preston, there's so much documentation it's ridiculous. That helps a lot!